# Select specific rows from a single table delimited by start and end rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

im not SQL programmer but having some basic skills. I need to extract specific rows from a single table delimited by start and end rows, for example

```
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| ID     | Type  | Information | Date                    | Comment      |
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 512    | 3     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:01:10.987 | Measurement  |
| 513    | 1     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:01:45.145 | Start        |            
| 514    | 3     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:02:11.207 | Measurement  |            
| 515    | 3     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:03:10.443 | Measurement  |            
| 516    | 2     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:03:56.897 | End          |            
| 517    | 3     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:04:10.491 | Measurement  |            
| 518    | 1     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:05:03.012 | Start        |            
| 519    | 3     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:05:11.229 | Measurement  |            
| 520    | 2     | { .... }    | 2021-01-06 10:05:30.472 | End          |                        
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

I need only type 3 rows between 1 and 2 but not between 2 and 1

Is it possible to do this in a single select?

Should I write a SP?

Thanks

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: rows with ID 514, 515 and 519. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have two 1s or 2s without reapective 2 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to get the most recent date for a "1" and "2 and compare those:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when type = 1 then date end) over (order by date) as date_1,
             max(case when type = 2 then date end) over (order by date) as date_2
      from t
     ) t
where type = 3 and
      (date_1 > date_2 or
       date_1 is not null and date_2 is null
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, `CROSS APPLY` to get the `end` and `start` records. Then `inner join` between `start` and `end` to get the records with `Type 3`.

```
select
    -- select only measurement records
    measurement.*

From YourTable startt
    -- calculate each end for each start
    CROSS APPLY
        (
            select Top (1)
                t.Date,
                t.Type,
                t.Comment
            From YourTable t
                where t.Type = 2
                    and t.Date >= startt.Date
                    -- order by date to get the most recent after startt
                order by t.Date
        ) endd
    -- join for type 3 between startt and endd
    INNER JOIN YourTable measurement
            on 
            measurement.Type = 3
            and measurement.Date >= startt.Date 
            and measurement <= endd.Date

    where startt.Type = 1
```